# Check if string is a date in Elixir

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am new to Elixir and wanted to know if there is a way to check if a string is a date without necessarily having to write your own function that makes use of regex?

Comment: What's the format of the date string?

Comment: String can be in any date time format

Comment: It's good to limit your potential input formats, because they can conflict. For example, "05-06-2017" could be valid as both May 6th or June 5th depending on what part of the world you're from.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the format of the date in the parsed string. `Elixir`'s standard library contains [Date.from_iso8601](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Date.html#from_iso8601/2), which can be used as the following:

```
def is_date?(date) do
  case Date.from_iso8601(date) do
    {:ok, _} -> true
    _ -> false
  end
end
```

If you're expecting a string of another format, then [Timex](https://github.com/bitwalker/timex) library may be useful for you, because it allows to specify the format of the parsed string. For example:

```
def is_date?(date) do
  case Timex.format(date, "{ISO:Extended}") do
    {:ok, _} -> true
    _ -> false
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess the most suitable option for you might be [Timex.parse](https://hexdocs.pm/timex/Timex.html#parse/2), but you could provide informations of your Date's format.

If you have a bit more complex format, I'm afraid that using your own "datetime helper" will be neccesary.